# API.AI vs. WIT.AI from analytics and logging aspects

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es, wit-ai

I am trying to build a chat-bot , and my question is about the bot logging and analytics parts in API.AI vs. WIT.AI

As a background - 
My bot is a simple one and does not require any fulfilment logic on my server since I can teach the bot how to answer on all scenario's without added data from my server.

So far I studied API.AI and found out that (feel free to correct me if I am wrong) - 
1. No bot analytics or logging support.
2. If I want to support logging on my server OR by a 3rd party (like dashbot.io), I HAVE to create a "fulfilment" logic for all intents so API.AI will send via webhooks the Json of the data to my server and then I can use the data to log it or send to 3rd party for logging.
This is a lot of un-needed work from my end to support fulfilment just for logging.

My question - is there a simpler solution on WIT.AI which does not require me to work on un-needed logic fulfilment in my server, but simply send the Json (or other formatted data) of the input & output between humans and my bot to my server for logging?